# Smarty / PHP: Why is it not possible to use two foreach loops in one table with Smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

Is it possible to use two different foreach loops in one table with Smarty?
I tried everything but it just doesnt seem to work. The $numrow array has 10 results, but only shows one and the same in all 10 rows.

Is this a common problem with Smarty?

```
<table width="500">   

{foreach from=$categories item=category}   
  {if $category.fcType == 'm'}
    <tr>
      <td><strong>{$category.fcName}</strong></td>
      <td>&nbsp</td>
  {else}
    <tr>
      <td><a href="http://localhost/ZendFramework/forum/category?c={$category.fcID}">{$category.fcName}</a></td>
      <td>{$category.fcDescription}</td>
    {foreach from=$numrows item=numrow} 
      <td>{$numrow}</td>
    {/foreach} 
  {/if}

  {if !empty($category.fuUsername)}
      <td>Nieuwste topic toegevoegd door {$category.fuUsername} op {$category.topic_date}</td>
  {else}
      <td>&nbsp</td> 
  {/if}
    </tr>        
{/foreach}  

</table>
```

php:

```
$getCat = isset($_GET['c']) ? $_GET['c'] : '';;
    $getCat = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($getCat));;

    $query_cat = "
    SELECT 
        forum_categories.fcID
        ,forum_categories.fcName
        ,forum_categories.fcDescription
        ,forum_categories.fcParent
        ,forum_categories.fcType
        ,forum_users.fuUsername
        ,DATE_FORMAT(forum_topics.ftDate,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS topic_date
    FROM
        forum_categories
    LEFT JOIN
        forum_topics
    ON
        forum_topics.fcID = forum_categories.fcID
    LEFT JOIN
        forum_users
    ON
        forum_topics.fuID = forum_users.fuID    
    GROUP BY
        forum_categories.fcID
    ORDER BY 
        forum_categories.fcPos 
    ";
    $exec_cat = mysql_query($query_cat);
    if (($exec_cat) and mysql_num_rows($exec_cat))
    {
        while($category = mysql_fetch_assoc($exec_cat))
        {           
            $query_count = "
            SELECT 
                forum_topics.ftID
            FROM
                forum_categories
            INNER JOIN
                forum_topics
            ON
                forum_categories.fcID = forum_topics.fcID
            WHERE forum_categories.fcID = '".$category['fcID']."'
            ";
            $exec_count = mysql_query($query_count);
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($exec_count);
            $numrows[] = $numrows;

            echo $numrows;

            $this->view->assign("numrows", $numrows);   


            $categories[] = $category; 
            $this->view->assign("categories", $categories);
        }

    }  
    else 
    {
        echo 'Er zijn nog geen categorieen aanwezig in de database.';
    }
```

Comment: Allright, So how can i display the results from two arrays in one table, without getting messy?

Comment: **{foreach} loops can be nested** *source:* http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach

Comment: Yeah found it myself and removed the comment, too late I guess :P You can nest them

Comment: With nesting you can show array from other php associativa array, within the foreach loop, so can someone explain me how it works with my code? I am not very experienced with smarty

Comment: What does `$categories` contain? I suppose the point is that you are iterating over the same variable `$numrows` on every iteration of `$categories` - the data never changes, so I would expect to see the same row for however many items there are in `$categories` with this code. Normally `$numrows` would come from some property of `$categories`...

Comment: in PHP i have two tables: one for displaying all the categories. And one table for counting the topics in one category. So as a result i have two associative arrays to use in Smarty. So i have to use two foreach loops. I just want to show the output of two SELECT statements which i put in arrays, and assigned to smarty in one HTML table.

Comment: You are parsing $numrows, but don't you need to print `numrows` from the `category` variable?  `{foreach from=$numrows item=$categorynumrow}`

Comment: i added my PHP code in the blog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 while($category = mysql_fetch_assoc($exec_cat))
    {           
        $query_count = "
        SELECT 
            forum_topics.ftID
        FROM
            forum_categories
        INNER JOIN
            forum_topics
        ON
            forum_categories.fcID = forum_topics.fcID
        WHERE forum_categories.fcID = '".$category['fcID']."'
        ";
        $exec_count = mysql_query($query_count);
        $category['numrows'] = mysql_num_rows($exec_count);
        $categories[] = $category;
    }
$this->view->assign("categories", $categories);
```

And in your Smarty TPL: `{foreach from=$category.numrows item=numrow}`

Aren't you BTW overwriting your categories assign in your loop? (Place the last assign outside the while loop)

Comment: do you mean:$this->view->assign("categories", $categories);  outside the while loop?

Comment: Yes. I changed my post. Can you try?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a different name in your foreach loops:

```
{foreach name = "loop1" from=$categories item='category'}
```

and

```
{foreach name = "loop2" from=$numrows item='numrow'}
```

I haven't tried it myself, but see if it makes any difference

(btw, remember to put a semicolon after the special html chars: it should be &nbsp; instead of &nbsp)